# Invalid Hook Call - useState function

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js and running into below error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem

The line where it fails:

```
const [scale, setScale] = useState(initialScale);
```

Code snippet is here:

```
import React, {
  useMemo,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useCallback,
  useImperativeHandle,
  forwardRef,
  Ref,
} from 'react';
import usePDF from './hooks/usePDF';
import useAnnotations from './hooks/useAnnotations';
import useTextMap from './hooks/useTextMap';
import Page from './components/Page';
import Error from './components/Error';
import ButtonGroup from './components/ButtonGroup';
import { Entity } from './interfaces/entity';
import { Annotation } from './interfaces/annotation';
import { TextLayer, TextLayerItem } from './interfaces/textLayer';
import { debug } from 'console';

interface Props {
  url?: string;
  data?: Uint8Array | BufferSource | string;
  httpHeaders?: {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
  initialScale?: number;
  tokenizer?: RegExp;
  disableOCR?: boolean;
  entity?: Entity;
  initialTextMap?: Array<TextLayer>;
  defaultAnnotations?: Array<Annotation>,
  getAnnotations(annotations: Array<Annotation>): void
  getTextMaps?(textMaps: Array<TextLayer>): void;
}

const Annotator = forwardRef(({
  url,
  data,
  httpHeaders,
  initialScale = 1.5,
  tokenizer = new RegExp(/\w+([,.\-/]\w+)+|\w+|\W/g),
  disableOCR = false,
  entity,
  initialTextMap,
  defaultAnnotations = [],
  getAnnotations,
  getTextMaps,
}: Props, ref?: Ref<any>) => {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(initialScale);

  const { pages, error, fetchPage } = usePDF({ url, data, httpHeaders });
  const {
    annotations,
    getAnnotationsForPage,
    addAnnotation,
    removeAnnotation: deleteAnnotation
  } = useAnnotations(defaultAnnotations);
  const { textMap, addPageToTextMap } = useTextMap(annotations);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ removeAnnotation }));

  const removeAnnotation = (id: string) => {
    deleteAnnotation(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (getAnnotations) {
      getAnnotations(annotations);
    }
    if (getTextMaps) {
      getTextMaps(initialTextMap || textMap);
    }
  }, [annotations, textMap, initialTextMap, getAnnotations, getTextMaps]);

  const getTextLayerForPage = useCallback((page: number): Array<TextLayerItem> | undefined => {
    if (initialTextMap) {
      const found = initialTextMap.find((layer) => layer.page === page);
      return found ? found.textMapItems : undefined;
    }
    return undefined;
  }, [initialTextMap]);

  const renderPages = useMemo(() => {
    if (!url && !data) {
      return (
        <Error
          message="You need to provide either valid PDF data or a URL to a PDF"
        />
      );
    }
    console.log('i am here')
    debugger
    // if (error) {
    //   return <Error />;
    // }

    return (
      Array(pages).fill(0).map((_, index) => {
        const key = `pdf-page-${index}`;
        const pageNumber = index + 1;
        const page = fetchPage(pageNumber);
        return (
          <Page
            page={page}
            scale={scale}
            key={key}
            tokenizer={tokenizer}
            disableOCR={disableOCR}
            pageNumber={pageNumber}
            annotations={getAnnotationsForPage(pageNumber)}
            addAnnotation={addAnnotation}
            removeAnnotation={deleteAnnotation}
            addPageToTextMap={addPageToTextMap}
            entity={entity}
            initialTextLayer={getTextLayerForPage(pageNumber)}
          />
        );
      })
    );
  }, [
    url, data, pages, error, scale, tokenizer, disableOCR, entity,
    fetchPage, getAnnotationsForPage, addAnnotation, deleteAnnotation, addPageToTextMap, getTextLayerForPage,
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="annotator-container">
      <div className="annotator-pages-container">
        <div className="annotator-pages">
          { renderPages }
        </div>
      </div>
      <ButtonGroup scale={scale} setScale={setScale} />
    </div>
  );
});

export default Annotator;
```

Comment: If not you then someone else posted this exact question/issue and code a day or two ago. I guess it's deleted though since I'm unable to locate it. I recall even looking over this code in the repo. I don't see any overt issues with the code. What debugging steps have you taken? Can you provide a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can live debug in?

Comment: Hi Drew, I would love to provide you one running code sandbox.... but m not sure how to do that.. if you can direct me to some google links... i will follow it.

Comment: when i run the command : npm view react version .. it shows 17.0.1.... in the dev dependencies i have it as 16.13.1... is that an issue....?? did you try cloning and installing the project

Comment: Sure, here's [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/). It's an online web IDE that is essentially a VSCode clone, so if you use VSCode at all it will be very familiar. You can even import a project *from* github directly. "did you try cloning and installing the project" - No, did you include a link to your project? I don't *think* just using React v17.0.1 would be an issue other than if the ReactDOM version is something different (1st item on that llist to check).

Comment: It fails when it goes to get dispatcher: var dispatcher = ReactCurrentDispatcher.current;

  and the next line its gone..

Comment: Thanks Drew... I have created a sandbox and imported the code there from github... url to sandbox is this: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-roentgen-mqjxc

Comment: Ah, this isn't a standalone project it seems. React/ReactDOM are listed as peer dependencies and I assume you are consuming this package in a project of yours. Is this correct? If you've React v17.x installed then perhaps that is the issue.

Comment: Yes there is an example project within that project: react-pdf-ner-annotator.... so the example project is consuming the react-pdf-ner-annotator ... when you do npm start on react-pdf-ner-annotator... it basically builds and runs example... ... its mentioned in the package.json

Comment: Finally got it working!! It was a react version issue that was causing that error.. not a code issue.

Comment: @abhi Which version works? I have the same issue using `18.2.0`